# Python - Excel on Linux - Is there a way to extract comments and hyperlinks?

Tags: python, linux, excel, openpyxl

Is there a way to extract cell comments and hyperlinks from an excel spreadsheet on Linux?

Just tried to get hyperlinks on openpyxl:

```
c = worksheet.cell('A378')
c.hyperlink
```

c.value returns the cell value / link text but .hyperlink returns an empty string although a link is there on the spreadsheet...

Perhaps there is another module to do this?

Comment: I'm seeing the same behavior on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `openpyxl`, then presumably you are working with .xlsx files.  For now, you probably have to roll your own (meaning you would have to unzip the .xlsx and look around for the relevant pieces yourself; Python does provide tools for these, but at a lower level than `openpyxl`).

If you can work with .xls instead, then you're in luck:  As of version 0.7.2, [`xlrd`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd) will read comments and hyperlinks.  Look for the `cell_note_map` and `hyperlink_map` sheet properties.  (Note that the latest version of `xlrd` (0.8.0) does read .xlsx files also, but without explicit support for comments or hyperlinks, so would put you in the same boat as `openpyxl` for now.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using openpyxl then use the hyperlink attribute of worksheet to get the hyperlink :

```
wb = load_workbook("file path")
ws= wb['Name of the sheet']

ws.cell(row = rowNumber , column = columnNUmber).hyperlink.target #this will give you the link as output .
```